# Is there support for mouse events in VSCode's integrated terminal on Windows?

Tags: bash, powershell, visual-studio-code, mouseevent, mouse

VSCode's integrated terminal supports mouse events on Linux and OS X. For example, if VIM is launched in the integrated terminal on these systems, you can use the mouse to move the cursor around and select text.

I can't seem to get the mouse to work in VSCode's integrated terminal on Windows 10. I can't even find any documentation on whether this is supposed to work or not. Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the combinations that I have tried:

| OS | Terminal | Shell | Application | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Windows 10.0.19044.3086 | Windows Terminal 1.17.11461.0 | Command Prompt | VIM 9.0.1786 | Mouse Works |
| Windows 10.0.19044.3086 | PowerShell 5.1.19041.3031 | PowerShell 5.1.19041.3031 | VIM 9.0.1786 | Mouse Works |
| Windows 10.0.19044.3086 | BASH 5.2.15(1)-release | BASH 5.2.15(1)-release | VIM 9.0.1786 | Mouse Works |
| Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS | VS Code 1.81.1 integrated terminal | BASH 5.2.15(1)-release | VIM 9.0.1786 | Mouse Works |
| Windows 10.0.19044.3086 | VS Code 1.81.1 integrated terminal | Command Prompt | VIM 9.0.1786 | Does not Work |
| Windows 10.0.19044.3086 | VS Code 1.81.1 integrated terminal | PowerShell 5.1.19041.3031 | VIM 9.0.1786 | Does not Work |
| Windows 10.0.19044.3086 | VS Code 1.81.1 integrated terminal | BASH 5.2.15(1)-release | VIM 9.0.1786 | Does not Work |

In every "Works" row, no configuration was required. Mouse works on a fresh install with the default configs.

Comment: My feeling is that mouse selection of text should work somehow, and unrelated to the shell you are running in the terminal. But you are asking this at the wrong place; Stackoverflow is for discussing programming problems. How to configure vscode is better asked in [su].

Comment: @user1934428 VS Code usage and functionality is generally on-topic here. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418698/11107541

Comment: @starball : Interesting link ... thanks a lot. I find these rules a bit confusing, but well, this is how it is ....

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, mouse selection of text works, in the sense that the integrated terminal treats the application as an unmodifiable wall of text, and I can freely select from this wall of static text. But the mouse cannot interact with the application in any way.

Comment: Could you provide an example for such an interaction? I was thinking that you are only talking about selecting text, and copy&paste.

Comment: @user1934428 There's a video of a VIM user using the mouse: https://vimtricks.com/p/using-a-mouse-in-vim/. Here's a video of my current VS code setup, with the mouse not working: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALbEzFiuvRM